# pull all non-zero elements in an array to the left - c#

Tags: c#, arrays

If I have the following array

```
{ 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1 }
```

And I want a method that will take the array and change it to

```
{ 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0 }
```

What would be the best algorithm to do this? Is it possible to do this in O(N) time?

this question is essentially my exact question except in python not c#, in case I was not clear: (only difference is move the zeros to the right, not left)
[how to move all non-zero elements in a python list or numpy array to one side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26966907/how-to-move-all-non-zero-elements-in-a-python-list-or-numpy-array-to-one-side)

Thanks

EDIT: I've ran into another problem that I didn't consider at first. I'm actually trying to run this algorithm on a 2d array, but only on one particular dimension. how would I change to account for this?

Comment: Just run a loop through the `List`, if it arrives at a zero, have it sent all the way to the end.

Comment: For the two-dimensional part, you'd have to be more specific on which dimension you are trying to "shift". The algorithm will depend on that. Best to provide sample desired input/output. I would almost consider it a separate question.

Comment: the sample array I gave would instead of being an array, would be a row inside a 2d array. I didn't think this would change it, but it obviously would... oops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### UPDATED FOR 2D ARRAY

```
int[,] array = 
{
    { 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1 }, // Row 0
    { 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1 }, // Row 1
    { 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1 }  // Row 2
};

PullNonZerosToLeft(array, 1);

for (int row = 0; row <= array.GetUpperBound(0); row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col <= array.GetUpperBound(1); col++)
    {
        Console.Write("{0} ", array[row,col]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

PullNonZerosToLeft()

```
public static void PullNonZerosToLeft(int[,] array, int row)
{
    if (row > array.GetUpperBound(0))
    {
        return;
    }

    // Used to keep track of the swap point
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= array.GetUpperBound(1); i++)
    {
        if (array[row, i] == 0)
        {
            continue;
        }

        int temp = array[row, i];
        array[row, i] = array[row, index];
        array[row, index] = temp;
        index++;
    }
}
```

Results:

```
1 0 0 1 2 0 1
1 2 1 1 0 0 0
1 0 0 1 2 0 1
```

### UPDATED FOR JAGGED ARRAY

A non-`Linq` approach, where you swap all non-zero elements with zero elements.

```
int[][] array = 
{
    new[] { 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1 }, // Row 0
    new[] { 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1 }, // Row 1
    new[] { 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1 }  // Row 2
};

PullNonZerosToLeft(array, 1);

foreach (int[] row in array)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", row));
}
```

PullNonZerosToLeft()

```
public static void PullNonZerosToLeft(int[][] array, int row)
{
    if (row >= array.Length)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Used to keep track of the swap point
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array[row].Length; i++)
    {
        if (array[row][i] == 0)
        {
            continue;
        }

        int temp = array[row][i];
        array[row][i] = array[row][index];
        array[row][index] = temp;
        index++;
    }
}
```

Results:

```
1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1
1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0
1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1
```

Comment: Just to clarify, this is a jagged array, whereas i was using a 2d array (int [,] vs int[][]). I think i need to change my code to use a jagged array though, the 2d array is limiting.

Comment: @ConnorJensen Yes you are correct about jagged vs 2D, but a jagged "can" be a 2D.  A 2D cannot be a jagged, which is why I chose the jagged route.  Updated answer to show an actual 2D array.  No real change in logic.

Comment: So I could use your code, but replace array[indexX][indexY] with array[indexX,indexY]?

Comment: @ConnorJensen Yes...  Just make note of the use of GetUpperBound() to avoid ArrayIndexOutOfBound Exceptions.

Comment: @ConnorJensen You're welcome.  If you found my answer helped you solve your question, kindly click the check mark next to my answer so your question is solved.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way you could do it.

```
var original = new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1 };
var nonZeroes = original.Where(x => x != 0); //enumerate once
var numberOfZeroes = original.Count() - nonZeroes.Count(); 
return nonZeroes.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(0, numberOfZeroes)).ToArray();
```

Comment: [`Enumerable.Repeat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348899(v=vs.100).aspx) could be better than `Range` + `Select`.

Comment: @soon i wasn't aware of that method, thanks. i'll update my answer.

Comment: I would avoid looping a second time to get the zero count, as that can be done during the first loop. (You'd have to drop the fancy LINQ expression though.) I suppose O(2n) is still O(n) in theory but in practice we might as well be faster if it's just as clear :-) See my answer for what I mean.

Comment: yeah, i'm pretty sure that doing `Count()` on an array should be O(1), but i wasn't sure if it would be on `nonZeroes.Count()` so I wasn't totally sure if it'd really be an improvement.

Comment: Clever to subtract the Counts.

Comment: Wouldn't this enumerate `nonZeroes` twice: once when doing the `Count` and again for `Concat`? (Because `nonZeroes` is not an array: it is an `IEnumerable<int>`.)

Comment: Actually I think that is true. The MSDN article on IEnumerable.Where() has a reminder that it uses deferred execution: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534803%28v=vs.100%29.aspx says

Comment: How would I change this to account for a 2d array? (see my edit)

Comment: that would be a different question alltogether.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do it in O(n) time and O(1) space complexity.
Start with a low pointer at 0 and a high pointer at last index of the array.
**Algorithm**:
1. Increment low till you find 0, decrement high till you find a non-zero number.
2. Swap Array[low] and Array[high].
3. Repeat steps 1 and 2 till low is less than high.

Comment: > till low is less than high.

Should be vice versa.

Comment: -1: While this algorithm produces the correct output with the sample array, in the general case it has a side effect of changing the order of the non-zero elements.

Comment: Yes, I need to keep the order of the non-zero elements the same

Comment: @ConnorJensen, you should've mentioned it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can just order by `n == 0`.

```
var original = new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1 };
var result = original.OrderBy(n => n == 0).ToArray();
```

Comment: I'm not sure how `OrderBy` runs internally, so this might actually be a `O(n log n)` operation.  But I like the thought.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it in O(n) time by creating a new array. Note that this avoids the penalty of looping through the array a second time to get the count of zeros, as in Dleh's answer.

```
public static int[] PushNonZeroToLeft(int[] aiArray)
{
    var alNew = new List<int>();
    var iZeroCount = 0;

    foreach (int i in aiArray)
        if (i > 0)
            alNew.Add(i);
        else
            iZeroCount++;

    alNew.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(0, iZeroCount));

    return alNew.ToArray();
}
```

Not sure if O(n) can be achieved if you have to mutate the original array...

Comment: okay I'll try that! how would I change this to account for a 2d array? (look at my edit)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an O(n) time, O(1) space algorithm for doing what you want.  It will also preserve the order of the non-zero elements.

```
var array = new []{ 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 0, 1 };
int j = 0;
for( int i = 0; i < array.Length && j < array.Length; ++i )
{
    if( array[i] != 0 ) continue;

    if( j <= i ) j = i + 1;

    while( j < array.Length && array[j] == 0 ) ++j;

    if( j >= array.Length ) break;

    var t = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = t;
}
```

Comment: -1: I think this actually approaches O(n^2) in time complexity for certain arrays. For example, consider an array with a large run of zeros: {1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}. The inner while loop is going to run almost as many times as there are elements.

Comment: @JordanRieger I don't think so, since j can only increment n times at most.  The j "pointer" can only ever move forwards through the array, never backwards.  As soon as j runs off the end of the array, the algorithm terminates.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I thought the j pointer was being reset in each iteration. Clever solution!

Comment: @JordanRieger Thanks for keeping an eye out!  This was actually based on the other O(n) solutions but I tweaked them to preserve the order of the non-zero items.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd approach it. Nice and simple. I didn't run performance tests but would expect it to be a little more performant than some of the suggestions that use LINQ, or create new arrays.

```
int[] array = { 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1 };

for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    if (array[i] == 0)
    {
        int j;

        for (j = i + 1; j < array.Length; j++)
        {
            if (array[j] != 0)
                break;
        }

        if (j < array.Length)
        {
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = 0;
        }
        else break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this is possible to do in O(N) time.

Basically:

1. Loop through the array
2. For every element you find that is non-zero, copy it

   - First element should be copied to position 0, next to position 1, etc. Keep track of how far you get with this position.
3. When you've looped through it, iterate the position you kept track of through the rest of the array until you reach the end, and keep setting elements to zero as you go.

The algorithm will *copy*, not *move*, so the 3rd point above will make sure any elements we copied but did not subsequently overwrite will be zeroed out afterwards.

Here's some example code:

```
int next = 0;

// copy all non-zero elements to the start
foreach (var element in collection)
    if (element != 0)
        collection[next++] = element;

// fill remainder with zeroes
while (next < collection.Count)
    collection[next++] = 0;
```

Comment: I believe the answer should be in C#, not python. (Didn't downvote, by the way.)

Comment: @Jashaszun looks like c# to me?

Comment: It wasn't to begin with, I wrote pseudo-code that looked like Python.